# GoDaddy Hosted Site Not Getting CodeIgniter Post

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, codeigniter-2

No matter what I do, I cannot get any results in my $_POST array. I use the standard .htaccess for CI, but $_POST does not populate.

It works on non-CI scripts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet this is the issue: http://www.highonphp.com/php-fastcgi-post-requests-failing

I ran into something similar going back when the 4G hosting came out for a client.

Change

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: omg, that did it. Someone I was talking to on IRC said something about QSA?